# Convergence of sequences in topological spaces after change of index by injection.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $x_n \to a$ in a topological space $X$ and that $\phi:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is injective. Show that $x_{\phi(n)} \to a$

My "attempt":

If $x_n \to a$ then for every open set $U$ containing $a$ there exists $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>n_{0}$, $x_n \in U$.

If I understand this correctly, I'm mixing the indexes of terms of the sequence by an injective function, and want to prove that will still be convergent.

$\phi$ is injective, then for every $x,y \in \mathbb{N}, \phi(x) \neq \phi(y)$. I can't see why this would't affect the convergence, can someone give me a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you considering nets or sequences?

Comment: HINT: Show that any two enumerations of the natural numbers agree on an infinite set, then use the fact that the original sequence is convergent.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is that generally true for countable sets? That's neat I had no idea.

Comment: @Pete: It's generally true for well ordered sets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'd never heard of that, that's really cool!

Comment: @Pete: http://mathoverflow.net/q/40507/7206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be an open set around $x$. We want to show that there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N \implies x_{\phi(n)} \in U$.

Now, we know that there is some $M$ such that $m > M \implies x_m \in U$.

Let $K = \max\{i \in \mathbb{N} : \phi(i) \leq M\}$. This exists because $\phi$ is one-one. Note that whenever $k > K$, then $\phi(k) > M$, so $x_{\phi(k)} \in U$. Thus, $x_{\phi(n)} \to x$.